# Adding a conditional logic without violating SOLID principles C#

Tags: c#, architecture, solid-principles

I have and interface and Implementation as below.
Where if a number is divisible by the devisor it will display the content called "Divisible".
Now the new enhancement came where I need to change the text based on the time.
If the number is divisible and the time is 12:00PM display "Divisible ***".If the time is not "12:PM" display the old value i:e "Divisible".
I know it can be done,But condition is that we should not violate SOLID principle.Whether the design which I have done is wrong? Please suggest.

```
public interface IRule
{
    string GetResult(int number);
}

public class DivisibleRule : IRule
{

    private readonly int divisor;


    private readonly string contentToDisplay;


    private readonly string replacementContent;


    public DivisibleRule(int divisor, string contentToDisplay)
    {
        this.divisor = divisor;
        this.contentToDisplay = contentToDisplay;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">The input.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the content if divisible.</returns>
    public string GetResult(int input)
    {
        return input % this.divisor == 0
             ?  this.contentToDisplay
            : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add this functionality without modifying the existing code (which is basically what [Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) is about) then you can add a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) which will apply the new conditional logic to result returned from already existing `DivisibleRule`. Then wherever it's appropriate you can use `DivisibleRule` decorated with your decorator.

This decorator can look something like this:

```
public class RuleTimeDecorator : IRule
{
    private readonly IRule _decoratedRule;

    public RuleTimeDecorator(IRule decoratedRule)
    {
        _decoratedRule = decoratedRule;
    }

    public string GetResult(int input)
    {
        var result = _decoratedRule.GetResult(input);

        return IsMidnight()? $"{result} ***" : result;
    }

    private bool IsMidnight() => //here goes the code to check if current time meets criteria 
}
```

Nice thing is that this decorator can be used to decorate any other implantation of `IRule` (as long as it makes sens in your domain).

BTW I'm using some C#6 features like string interpolation and expression bodied members but that's not required.